# Yii2 - Update Complex Form

Tags: yii2

I created a Complex Form using two Model Classes:

1. Courses
2. CourseStructure

   ```
   public function actionCreate()
   {
   $model = new Course();
   $request = Yii::$app->request;

   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    //The course was created successfully, so we can use its data to make course structure
   \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
           return ActiveForm::validate($model);
   }
   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {  

   $model->attributes = $_POST['Course'];
   $model->course_start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['Course']['course_start_date']));
   $model->created_at = new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()');

   }          
       $model->save(false);   

       if($model->save(false))
       //The course was created successfully, so we can use its data to make course structure
       {
         // check if topic format 
           if($model->course_format == Course::TYPE_TOPIC) 
           {      
               for( $i = 1; $i <= $model->course_format_no; $i++ )
               {
                   $structure = new CourseStructure();
                   $structure->course_id = $model->course_id;                  
                   $structure->structure_name = $model->course_format . $i;
                   $structure->structure_id = $i;

                   // fill in other course structure data here
                   $structure->save();
               }
           }
       }                      
       else
           return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model,]);


   } else {
       return $this->render('create', [
           'model' => $model,
       ]);
   }
   }
   ```

From CourseControllers, if course_format = TYPE_TOPIC, then based on the course_format_no selected,
some rows are added in course_structure table (CourseStructure). For instance, if course_format_no = 3, it creates three additional rows in course_structure table.

```
                if($model->course_format == Course::TYPE_TOPIC) 
            {      
                for( $i = 1; $i <= $model->course_format_no; $i++ )
                {
                  $structure = new CourseStructure();
                    $structure->course_id = $model->course_id;                  
                    $structure->structure_name = $model->course_format . $i;
                    $structure->structure_id = $i;

                    // fill in other course structure data here
                    $structure->save();
                }
            }
```

It works fine in CourseCreate Action in CourseController.

Now how do I do it for the CourseUpdate Action, so that if that either reduce the number of rows or increase it in course_structure table based on the course_format_no added in the update.

[course_structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPINR.png)

This is what I have:

```
    public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);
    $old_model = $this->findModel($id);

if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ActiveForm::validate($model);
    }
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {

    $model->attributes = $_POST['Course'];
    $model->course_start_date = Yii::$app->dateformatter->getDateFormat($_POST['Course']['course_start_date']);       

    $model->updated_by = Yii::$app->getid->getId();
    $model->updated_at = new \yii\db\Expression('NOW()');
    if($model->save(false))
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->course_id]);

    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**CourseStructure model**

```
class CourseStructure extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'course_structure';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['course_id', 'structure_id', 'summary_format', 'created_by', 'updated_by'], 'integer'],
        [['structure_summary'], 'string'],
        [['created_at', 'updated_at'], 'safe'],
        [['structure_name'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'course_structure_id' => 'Course Structure ID',
        'course_id' => 'Course ID',
        'structure_id' => 'Structure ID',
        'structure_name' => 'Structure Name',
        'structure_summary' => 'Structure Summary',
        'summary_format' => 'Summary Format',
        'created_at' => 'Created At',
        'created_by' => 'Created By',
        'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        'updated_by' => 'Updated By',
    ];
}

public function getCourses()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Course::className(), ['course_id' => 'course_id']);
}   

public static function getAllCourseStructure()
{
    $dataTmp = self::find()->orderBy('structure_name')->all();
    $result = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($dataTmp, 'course_structure_id', 'structure_name');
    return $result;
}     
}
```

**Courses model**

```
class Course extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
const TYPE_WEEKLY= 'Weekly';
const TYPE_TOPIC='Topic';  

public $coursefile;

public static function tableName()
{
    return 'course';
}

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['course_category_id', 'course_format_no', 'show_grade', 'created_by', 'updated_by'], 'integer'],
        [['course_code', 'course_name', 'course_format', 'course_format_no'], 'required', 'message' => ''],
        [['course_summary'], 'string'],
        [['course_start_date', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'course_file_path'], 'safe'],
        [['course_code'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
        [['course_name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
        [['course_num', 'course_format'], 'string', 'max' => 20],
        [['course_code'], 'unique'],
        [['coursefile'], 'safe'],

        [['course_name', 'course_category_id'], 'unique', 'targetAttribute' => ['course_name', 'course_category_id'], 'message' => Yii::t('app', 'The combination of Course Name and Course Category has already been taken.')],
        [['coursefile'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'jpg, jpeg, gif, png, pdf, txt, jpeg, xls, xlsx, doc, docx', 'maxFiles' => 4],
        [['coursefile'], 'file', 'maxSize'=>'10000000'],
        [['course_file_path', 'course_file_name'], 'string', 'max' => 255],        
    ];
}

public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'course_id' => 'Course ID',
        'course_category_id' => 'Course Category',
        'course_code' => 'Course Short Name',
        'course_name' => 'Course Full Name',
        'course_num' => 'Course ID Number',
        'course_summary' => 'Course Summary',
        'course_start_date' => 'Course Start Date',
        'course_format' => 'Course Format',
        'course_format_no' => 'No.of Sections',
        'course_file_path' => Yii::t('app', 'Pathname'),          //'Course File',
        'course_file_name' => Yii::t('app', 'Filename'),
        'show_grade' => 'Show Grade',
        'created_at' => 'Created At',
        'created_by' => 'Created By',
        'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        'updated_by' => 'Updated By',
    ];
}

public function getCourseCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(CourseCategories::className(), ['course_category_id' => 'course_category_id']);
}   

public static function getAllCourse()
{
    $dataTmp = self::find()->orderBy('course_name')->all();
    $result = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($dataTmp, 'course_id', 'course_name');
    return $result;
}  

public static function getCourseFormat()
{
return[
Yii::t('app', self::TYPE_TOPIC) => Yii::t('app', 'Topic'),
Yii::t('app', self::TYPE_WEEKLY) => Yii::t('app', 'Weekly'),
];
}

}
```

How do I write the code to update CourseStructure in the ActionUpdate.

Comment: your question is incomplete you didn't shared the model neither you mentioned that the model that consists of the fields based on other 2 models is extending `ActiveRecord` or `yii\base\model`

Comment: Muhammad Omer Aslam, I have added the two models. Thanks